# Query AD User if wWWHomePage contains

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to query some AD users in PowerShell.
Some of those users have the *Web Page* field filled, and I would like to query users which field begins with "/site".

Is it possible to achieve that with the LDAPFilter in PowerShell?

Comment: `Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(&(wwwhomepage=/site*))'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(wWWHomePage=/site*)" -Properties wWWHomePage`

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!